# Error al descomprimir archivo zip en hosting

Tags: hosting, zip, upload

Saludos estoy intentando subir un archivo zip a mi hosting con un proyecto Laravel terminado, pero cuando intento descomprimir este estando en la carpeta de un subdominio que le cree siempre recibo advertencias “inflating” y finalmente todos los archivos no son descomprimidos; por lo tanto, el proyecto no funciona. Mi proveedor de hosting dice que es problema de mi compresor (WinRAR) y que ellos pueden subir los archivos por mí, pero esa no es una solución de fondo. Agradezco si alguien puede darme alguna mano en este asunto que me esta complicando bastante la vida.

[image: Error al subir archivo zip al hosting]

Comment: Intenta comprimiendo los archivos con otro programa cono 7z, a la vez puedes probar otros formatos como tar o tar.gz, lo cuales provee este programa.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, con la extencion tar funciono.

Comment: Fue un placer :)